# Can not start EC2 instance - "Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have 50 instances. I am running 30 instances (with multi instance type), then I cannot run another instance. The error:

> Error starting instances
>
> Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1

I can not start instance with number > 30.

How to increase limit instance running?

Comment: Read [ec2-resource-limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)

Comment: This is limit for each instance type, i cann't find info to increate limit instance running ( running state).

Comment: The limits are meant for running instances. You are allowed to run only x instances of each instance type. x is the limit, you can request for a limit raise.

Comment: I have limit:
 t2.medium => limit = 30
g2.2xlarge => limit = 30
c4.4xlarge => limit = 30
t1.micro => limit = 30
And runing:
g2.2xlarge = 17
t2.medium = 5
t1.micro = 7
So, the total running is 29
And i can not start instance continue?

Answer (score 17):

There are [resource limits](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html) to the number of Amazon EC2 instances that be run concurrently -- in total and per instance type.

The easiest way to view these limits and to request an increase is via the **Limits** option in the Amazon EC2 management console:

[image: Amazon EC2 limits console]

The first line shows the limit related to **Total number of On-Demand EC2 Instances**.

Comment: At the first line, I click to " Request limit increase", then show "Create Case" screen, howerver, it is increase for only instance type, not for all.

Comment: True! Just add an explanation in the **Use Case** to say that you want to increase your total limit, rather than a per-instance limit. It will be reviewed by Customer Service and they'll notice your comment.